# New to VBA, need simple script to check/alter cell value with loop

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry, total starter.

I want a VBA script that changes a cell value until another cell value (depending on the first cell) meets a condition. I guess I need the cells to update, or do they automatically?

So far I have gotten to this point:

```
Sub SetTime()
Dim t As Integer ' additional time in hours (integer)
Dim e As Single ' energy as float
t = 0 ' initialize
e = Range("J35").Value
     While e >= 1
         Range("J32").Value = t
         e = Range("J35").Value
         t = t + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

What this script should do:

1. Set cell J32 to 0
2. J35 changes because cell J32 changed
3. evaluate cell J35 if it meets the condition
4. if it doesn't: increase cell value of cell J32 by 1, go to step 2, if it does: go to step 5
5. finish, cell J32 should display the last value used

What it does:

Nothing

Comment: You never modify ```J35``` so if it is >=1 you now have an infinite loop, is it is <1 you skip the loop.

Comment: For your code to do anything, cell **A35** must contain a *formula.*  **please update your question to specify the formula contained in cell A35**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Correct, there is a formula in J35. The formula is (basically) this:
J35 = H35 / I35
where I35 = A1 + J32
and H35 is a fixed value

So it's a bit convoluted. There is an initial value in A1 and I want to see how many more hours I need to wait until the quotient falls below 1

Comment: @Warcupine J35 should be modified as soon as J32 is changed. I don't know if I must do this explicitly or if Excel does this automatically.

Comment: Based on the information you gave about the formula I can't reproduce the issue, it works for me. Maybe you have calculations set to manual?

Comment: File --> Options --> Formulas --> Workbook Calculations  or at the start of the sub ```Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic```

Comment: @Warcupine - Thank you!!
It works!

Answer (score 0):

(Too much information for a comment. I'll edit this as the answer once everything is clear)

So you want to change the content of a cell, from the moment that the value of another cell changes. In Excel this can be done in two ways:

- Use a formula
- Use the `Worksheet_Change` event (the input parameter is the range, being changed).

Can you give some background on what you want and why (what are the meanings of J32 and J35, why should they change and what should they change into)? This might make it possible to do what you want.

Comment: Ok.
I already use formulas. I have a quotient (bascially J35 / something + J32) and I need this quotient to get below 1.

Comment: Are you aware of the `solver` feature in Excel? You enter a formula, you say which value you need to get (1 in your case) and you say which cell value might be adapted for achieving this value and the solver calculates this.

Comment: No! Thanks! I'll try this!

Comment: @ Dominique thank you! Solver got me the correct answer. I have one question left:
Is there a way to run this process automatically again when I change any of two specific cells?

Comment: Yes, you might do this combining the Worksheet_Change event together with the solver. In order to do this, you might record a macro in order to know how solver works in VBA and adapt the recorded macro accordingly.